# How can I avoid Cartesian in DataFrame join in Scala?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Please refer following dataframes

I want to get mismatching rows in col2 after matching col1 of both dataframes
I am trying following but it's not producing result because seems the Dataframe join is forming Cartesian

```
val dfs = Seq((1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,6)).toDF("col1","col2")
val dft = Seq((1,1),(1,2),(1,4)).toDF("col1","col2") 

dfs.join(dft,"col1").filter(dfs("col2").notEqual(dft("col2"))).show
```

In above case I expect the join & filter to return result (1,3) 
But seems it's joining every row of col1 in dfs to every row in col1 on dft thus producing unwanted result

Is the Cartesion as following normal behaviour for Dataframe join or I am missing some setting? how can I get (1,3) as output?

```
scala> dft.join(dfs,dft("col1")===dfs("col1")).show
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col1|col2|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   1|   1|   3|
|   1|   1|   1|   2|
|   1|   1|   1|   1|
|   1|   2|   1|   3|
|   1|   2|   1|   2|
|   1|   2|   1|   1|
|   1|   4|   1|   3|
|   1|   4|   1|   2|
|   1|   4|   1|   1|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Thanks
chetab

Comment: Using "leftouter" is taking  close but again for removing extra records in "col1" use of except or intersect I guess would be costlier
dfs.join(dft,dfs("col1")===dft("col1") && dfs("col2")===dft("col2"),"leftouter")
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col1|col2|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   1|   1|   1|
|   1|   2|   1|   2|
|   1|   3|null|null|
|   2|   6|null|null|
+----+----+----+----+

Comment: did you resolve this issue, i'm also looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is not Cartesian product. You join by `col1` so output contains all combinations of row with matching `col1`. Result  is correct.